Lagrangian Formulation in Non-Conservative Systems
I am working in a non-conservative system. Would it make a difference if I

Formulate the Lagrange Equation with an additional term on the right hand side of the equation to account for the Rayleigh Dissipation Function, and derive the equation of motion
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot \theta_k} \right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta_k} = - \frac{\partial R}{\partial \dot \theta_k}
$$
versus

treating the system as conservative and formulate the standard Euler-Lagrange Equation =0, derive the equation of motion, then add in a dissipation term to the equation of motion.



Is the derivation from action principle to euler lagrange still holding? I remember there being assumptions on the way, for example for the boundary conditions but maybe more things. If it doesn't hold maybe you need a different action principle.

It is usually preferable to start from a coherent system, i.e. the first approach. The 2nd approach, you are doing serious violence upon the whole system by throwing in the dissipation term out of nowhere.

Echoing @naturallyInconsistent the method 1 & 2 will often lead to the same EOM, although the 2nd method seems morally wrong/corrupt/inconsistent. Related: How do non-conservative forces affect Lagrange equations?

"The classical mechanics of non-conservative systems", C. R. Galley, Phys. Rev. Lett. 110, 174301 (2013) https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.2745

@Emil thank you, I have not considered this point. So do you mean since the Maupertuis' principle requires conservation of energy, but the Hamilton's principle does not, I should be using the Hamilton's Principle instead?

@EeKinChan I don't remember which principle assumes what. But I think one of them required a known state at two points in time which I don't know if it works. I think d'Alembert virtual work thing was the one with the least assumptions, I think that one pretty much just said the dynamics of the system will go somewhere it is allowed to go. But I only took one course on this some doctor should answer you instead.

Okay I asked chatGPT and I think I mixed up Hamilton's principle with Hamiltonian mechanics. S/he/it said the principle did not require the phase space volume to be conserved, so maybe the principle is more general. But I don't feel confident yet. Anyway, when in doubt I would do the variational calculus derivation myself for one principle I know works in the particular case. I am reading up a bit on this know, found a free physics book on it.

Here is the book fyi https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics

I expect a difference.
The relation between energies as expressed by the Euler-Lagrange equation has assured validity only when all the potentials involved are potentials of conservative forces.
I assume that when you write: 'derive the equation of motion' you mean that you execute the differentiations specified by the Euler-Lagrange equation
Once those differentiations have been executed the result is in terms of generalized force and generalized acceleration. If you are going to add a frictional term, that is the expression to add it to.
(The word 'dissipation' is associated with the concept of energy. The equation in terms of (generalized) force and (generalized) acceleration is not in terms of energy, so in that context it seems better to me to use the concept of friction rather than the word 'dissipation'.)

I guess it may be tempting to port the frictional term back to the form of the Euler-Lagrange equation. I recommend against that, if only for this purpose: the validity of the Euler-Lagrange equation is assured only when all forces involved are conservative forces. If you limit yourself to use the Euler-Lagrange equation with conservative force potentials only then you have that guaranteed validity.
If you do add a term corresponding to a non-conservative force then a valid result is still possible, but if it happens to yield a valid result it's a fluke.

The dissipation terminology should be coming straight from Goldstein. You should not be writing things so definitively when you are not sure of the thing you are writing about. It is particularly egregious when the OP literally sourced the terminology "Rayleigh Dissipation Function", i.e. it is not plucked out of thin air, and that terminology is inside Goldstein too. You could have Google'd that term and checked that it is standard physics.
